# "On being excellent to each other“ engraved on a wedding ring?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality, expressions, phrase-requests

Would it be all right to have "On being excellent to each other“ as an engraving on a wedding ring?
The ring is meant as a symbol to celebrate our long time partnership, so it shall be read like a toast (here’s to being excellent to one another).

Comment: *On Being Excellent to Each Other* sounds like the title of a book, essay or manual on how to get on well

Comment: It would be inappropriate, unless your partner's ring says, "Party on, dudes!" or "Dust.  Wind.  Dude."  or "It's a history report, not a babe report," or, more to the point, "Wyld Stallyns rule!" https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096928/quotes/?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to use the preposition "To" instead of "On"?

Comment: @SeligkeitIstInGott I’m not sure. You think „To being excellent to one another“ is better? There is two times the word „to“...

Comment: The redundancy is not ideal. But "To" makes it sound more like a celebration, almost like a toast. Maybe replace the second "to" with "toward"?

Comment: @SeligkeitIstInGott Good idea. Thank you!

Comment: **On being excellent to each other.** is a nice remembrance of the event. At most weddings, the bride and groom are on their best behavior to each other, they dress well for the occasion, and so on. The inscription proposed by the OP could be read as a reminder that when the rings were exchanged, both parties were consciously trying to do their best for each other.  Personally I wouldn’t read this as a toast. Besides, even if you take off the rings for an anniversary celebration, you can still say “to being excellent to each other”. Not everything has to be spelled out exactly.

Comment: Much too long. It would be unreadable.

Comment: @GlobalCharm So you’re saying if you see the ring as a symbol or beacon of having been good to each other and wanting to continue to do so, it is correctly used?

Comment: @user371070 Yes, in my opinion it can be read that way. Some people might think that “excellent” is an overused word at the moment, but in 10 or 20 years this will change, so it might actually be a very good choice. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore Jim101.  Its not what i would go for, but all that matters is you and your fiancé/wife understand it.  No one else reading that will get it off the bat. The reason being toasts are not proper sentences and make sense in context of a raised glass. Not on a ring. But who will see it and why do you care what anyone other than your intended thinks?

Comment: I care because my intended insists on proof that it is „correct English“